# show $f(x)\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. If $\displaystyle \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f(x)|dx<\infty$ and $\displaystyle \int^\infty_{-\infty} |f^\prime(x)|dx<\infty$ show that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

Let $\epsilon >0$ WTS that $|f(x)|<\epsilon $ for some $N\in(c,\infty)$ such that $|x|>N$ , $c$ is some real number. Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(b)=0$ , so we have $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(b)|=|\displaystyle \int^b_x f^\prime(x)dx|<\int^\infty_{-\infty}|f^\prime(x)|dx$, now I just dont see a way of arguing towards the definition of limit. can someone give me a hint or help? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit on geetha290krm's answer, following their idea you can show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. Suppose now that $f(x)\to\alpha\neq0$ as $x\to\infty$. Let $R\in(0,\lvert \alpha\rvert )$. By the definition of the limit, there then exists some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert>R$ for all $x\geq x_0$. But this would then imply that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x\geq\int_{x_0}^\infty\lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x\geq\int_{x_0}^\infty R~\mathrm{d}x=\infty,$$

which contradicts that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x<\infty$. Thus we must have that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \int_x^{y}|f'(t)|dt \to 0$ as $y >x \to \infty$. This implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists. If this limit is not $0$ then $f$ would not be integrable.